# jQuery drag scroll like iPhone, in iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios-simulator

I'm working on a website with a iPhone which has a `iFrame` as screen. It would be very nice, if you could drag scroll, like you do on the iPhone.

A plugin* is already made, but I doesn't work with `iframes` and I've spend all day trying to make it do so - without any luck... :-(

The plugin that doesn't support `iframes` :
http://www.azoffdesign.com/overscroll

Can any of you help me on this one??

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go.....

Nicescroll : A jQuery Plugin that mimics iOS native scroll for browsers.

https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll